# Process an array of API calls sequentially with Bluebird.mapSeries

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

What I've been trying is to process API calls sequentially, which are pushed into an array.

```
function resolveApi(callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve(callback) });
}

function callApi(){

    var promises = [];
    promises.push(resolveApi(Restangular.one("api/blahblah",{/*input data*/})));
    promises.push(resolveApi(Restangular.one("api/another/api",{/*input data*/})));
    //there are other similar API calls.
    //Restangular is supposed to return an API call

    promises = Bluebird.mapSeries(promises, function(item, index) {
        return item;     
    });

    promises.then(function(){/* the end */});
}
```

The goal is to process each of the API calls in `promises` array, but the code above doesn't do this. (i.e. API calls are called almost simultaneously, while each API call is supposed to wait until the previous one is done.)

Do you see anything I'm doing wrong?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Every time you use a promise, you _must_ add a `catch` clause.

Comment: For any async system to work, you need some type of completion callback for your async operation.  Is `Restangular.one()` asynchronous?  If so, then does it have a completion callback?  You seem to be assuming that promises have some magic power to know when an async operation is done.  They do NOT have such power.  You have to tell them when the async operation is done by using some sort of completion callback that is called by the async operation itself.  The promises are just a more convenient way of managing completions.

Comment: So, your `resolveApi()` function does not do anything useful.  Until you solve that `Bluebird.mapSeries()` can't do it's work.  You need to pass it a function that return promises that are resolved ONLY when the underlying asynchronous operation is done.  You are resolving immediately and not waiting for the actual async operation to be done.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you for your advice, but I'm still a bit clueless. `Restangular.one()` is asynchronous. Perhaps I should say that this returns a Promise object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if `Restangular.one()` returns a promise (which your comment now indicates) and you want to process these api calls sequentially (one after the other), then you just have to organize the arguments to Bluebird's `.mapSeries()` correctly.  It takes an array of data and a function (that operates on that data and returns a promise).

So, let's organize your stuff that way:

```
const data = [
    {endPoint: "http://somedomain.com/api/blahblah", args: [1,2]},
    {endPoint: "http://somedomain.com/api/another/api", args: ["a", "b"]},
    {endPoint: "http://somedomain.com/api/yetanother", args: ["abc"]},
];

Promise.mapSeries(data, function(dataObj) {
    return Restangular.one(dataObj.endPoint, ...dataObj.args);
}).then(results => {
    // array of results here
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    // error occurred here
    console.log(err);
});
```

Since you said that `Restangular.one()` already returns a promise, I don't see any reason why you need to wrap it in your `resolveApi()` function.  That isn't needed and we certainly don't need to turn a promise into a plain callback to use `.mapSeries()`.

---

There were lots of things missing in your implementation, but the main one was that you were calling all the asynchronous operations immediately and then trying to manage the promises.  That will not sequence your operations.  That runs them all in parallel.  Further if you give `.mapSeries()` an array of promises, it can't sequence the operations because they've all already been started.  To let it manage when the asynchronous operations are started so that it can sequence them, you have to pass it an array of data and a function to call that is passed an item of that data and will return a promise.  Then, it can call them one at a time and your operations will get started one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

`resolveApi(Restangular.one("api/blahblah",{/*input data*/}))` is not a real Promise, which will resove the `callback` immediately

I guess you want to resolve after all ajax succeeds, `Promise.all` runs in parallel this is the fastest way, like this:

```js
Promise.all([
  Restangular.one("api/blahblah", { /*input data*/ }),
  Restangular.one("api/blahblah", { /*input data*/ }),
  ...
]).then((resultArray) => {
  //all finish
  console.log(resultArray)
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

or sequentially

```js
Promise.mapSeries([
  ["api/blahblah", { /*input data*/ }],
  ["api/blahblah", { /*input data*/ }],
  ...
], (item) => Restangular.one(item[0], item[1])).then(() => {
  //done
}).catch((e) => {

})
```

and more, you may want to use one ajax's result in next ajax, you can use 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/chain-promise, code might look like

```js
var chainPromise = require("chain-promise");

const params = [
  ["api/blahblah"],
  ["api/blahblah"],
]

chainPromise(params.map((p) => {
  return (data) => Restangular.one(p[0], data)
}), initData).then(() => {
  console.log('done')
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Before I mark your approach as a solution, would you be able to elaborate on why `resolveApi(Restangular.one("",{})` isn't a "real Promise"? According to the documentation, this will surely return a promise object. (https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#differences-with-resource)

Comment: when we use Promise, we deal async logic, `resolveApi(Restangular.one("",{})` this according to `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve(callback) });` this works just as `return Promise.resolve(callback)` thus, it will resolve immediately but not waiting for ajax to finish. so it is `not a real async logic Promise as you wished`

Answer (score 0):

Well OK you may use a small recursive utility to sequence promises one after another. I have two implementations here

1. This one will handle the errors if any are thrown and continue with the next promise. I use `.finally()` so make sure your browser is recent.

```js
var simulatePromisifiedAPI = (delay,data) => new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(_ => Math.random() > 0.1 ? v(data) : x(`error @ ${data}`), delay)),
    promises               = Array(10).fill(simulatePromisifiedAPI),
    sequencePromises       = ([api,...apis]) => apis.length ? api(250,`task no ${10-apis.length}`).then(v => console.log(`Doing something with the API data ${v}`))
                                                                                                  .catch(e => console.log(`Opps... Just got ${e}`))
                                                                                                  .finally(_ => sequencePromises(apis))
                                                            : api(250,"final").then(v => console.log(`Doing something with the API data ${v}`))
                                                                              .catch(e => console.log(`Opps... Just got ${e}`));

sequencePromises(promises);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
height : 100%;
max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or you may just like to cut the sequencing process if any of the promises in the chain rejects. Then simply remove `.finally()` part and insert the `sequencePromises(apis)` instruction into the `.then()` stage.

```js
var simulatePromisifiedAPI = (delay,data) => new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout(_ => Math.random() > 0.1 ? v(data) : x(`error @ ${data}`), delay)),
    promises               = Array(10).fill(simulatePromisifiedAPI),
    sequencePromises       = ([api,...apis]) => apis.length ? api(250,`task no ${10-apis.length}`).then(v => (console.log(`Doing something with the API data ${v}`), sequencePromises(apis)))
                                                                                                  .catch(e => console.log(`Opps... Just got ${e}`))
                                                            : api(250,"final").then(v => console.log(`Doing something with the API data ${v}`))
                                                                              .catch(e => console.log(`Opps... Just got ${e}`));

sequencePromises(promises);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
height : 100%;
max-height: 100% !important;
}
```